# Is it possible to have none value for some points in google charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Let's say I want to add moving average of 3 this means I don't have value for 1 and 2nd value. Google Charts draws emty string as if it was 0 which is ugly when drawing the chart, is it possible to prevent it ?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Candlestick', 'Begin', 'End', 'High'],
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
  ]);

  // add column for line, add data to rows...
  var colIndex = data.addColumn('number', 'Line');
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, "");
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, data.getValue(i, 1));
  }

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use value of --> `null`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Candlestick', 'Begin', 'End', 'High'],
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
  ]);

  // add column for line, add data to rows...
  var colIndex = data.addColumn('number', 'Line');
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, null);
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, data.getValue(i, 1));
  }

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

but of course, you don't *have* to set any value...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Candlestick', 'Begin', 'End', 'High'],
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
  ]);

  // add column for line, add data to rows...
  var colIndex = data.addColumn('number', 'Line');
  for (var i = 2; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, data.getValue(i, 1));
  }

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works. What if I now use static data (see below): setting null value doesn't seem to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Weird it doesn't work with literal value

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Candlestick', 'Begin', 'End', 'High', 'MA'],
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45, null],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66, null],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80,40],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50,40],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15,40]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```